# Pool allocator implementation

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocator

I have two questions about pool allocator implementation:

1. In given pool allocator implementation how can I check that void*
   pointer that I pass to deallocate function is exactly one of those
   that I allocated previously?
2. What should I do to allocate size
   of memory bigger than size of block? Just calculate amount of blocks
   that would be enough to fit given size and move my next free element pointer x blocks forward, where x is amount of blocks I need ?

   ```
   class Pool_c { // Basic type define
       typedef unsigned int uint;
       typedef unsigned char uchar;

       uint m_numOfBlocks; // Num of blocks
       uint m_sizeOfEachBlock; // Size of each block
       uint m_numFreeBlocks; // Num of remaining blocks
       uint m_numInitialized; // Num of initialized blocks
       uchar* m_memStart; // Beginning of memory pool
       uchar* m_next; // Num of next free block
   public:
       Pool_c()
       {
           m_numOfBlocks = 0;
           m_sizeOfEachBlock = 0;
           m_numFreeBlocks = 0;
           m_numInitialized = 0;
           m_memStart = NULL;
           m_next = 0;
       }
       ~Pool_c() { DestroyPool(); }
       void CreatePool(size_t sizeOfEachBlock,
           uint numOfBlocks)
       {
           m_numOfBlocks = numOfBlocks;
           m_sizeOfEachBlock = sizeOfEachBlock;
           m_memStart = new uchar[m_sizeOfEachBlock * m_numOfBlocks];
           m_numFreeBlocks = numOfBlocks;
           m_next = m_memStart;
       }
       void DestroyPool()
       {
           delete[] m_memStart;
           m_memStart = NULL;
       }
       uchar* AddrFromIndex(uint i) const
       {
           return m_memStart + (i * m_sizeOfEachBlock);
       }
       uint IndexFromAddr(const uchar* p) const
       {
           return (((uint)(p - m_memStart)) / m_sizeOfEachBlock);
       }
       void* Allocate()
       {
           if (m_numInitialized < m_numOfBlocks) {
               uint* p = (uint*)AddrFromIndex(m_numInitialized);
               *p = m_numInitialized + 1;
               m_numInitialized++;
           }
           void* ret = NULL;
           if (m_numFreeBlocks > 0) {
               ret = (void*)m_next;
               --m_numFreeBlocks;
               if (m_numFreeBlocks != 0) {
                   m_next = AddrFromIndex(*((uint*)m_next));
               }
               else {
                   m_next = NULL;
               }
           }
           return ret;
       }
       void DeAllocate(void* p)
       {
           if (m_next != NULL) {
               (*(uint*)p) = IndexFromAddr(m_next);
               m_next = (uchar*)p;
           }
           else {
               *((uint*)p) = m_numOfBlocks;
               m_next = (uchar*)p;
           }
           ++m_numFreeBlocks;
       }
   ```

Comment: As for your 1st question: Keep those pointers in a list and look them up.

Comment: (1) put signature bytes in your block control structure and check them.  (2) why are you writing an allocator for random sized memory blocks (use the default one) specialist allocators are best used when you know in advance the size range of the memory blocks you have to allocate.

Comment: @RichardCritten "put signature bytes in your block..." can't exactly understand what do you mean. I know size of blocks, but if I have like 100byte blocks and need to allocate 250 bytes, what should I exactly do in this situation ?